# Google Maps Business Geocoding using Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, server-side, google-geocoder

In the Google API Console, the API Access generates keys for `server`, `browser`, `Android`, and `iOS`.

1. Which type of api_key do I need to generate geocoding from Google App Engine Python?
2. If the answer is the server, do I need to find out the server's IP address for GAE, what are they? I got `74.125.129.141`, which can probably change. (or would it?)
3. Can you help me find an example to generate the code if you have a Python GAE server I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing?

I have this code, which displays the `data` from the `result.content`. My purpose is to save the geocode to the database using `ndb.GeoPt(lat,lng)`:

```
def get_geo(address):
  browser_key = "browser_key"
  server_key = "server_key"
  address = cgi.escape(address.replace(" ","+"))
  sensor = "true"
  url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key="+ server_key +"&address=" + address + "&sensor="+ sensor
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
  data = json.loads(result.content) # This is the error
  geo = data
  #lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
  #long = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
  #return ndb.GeoPt(str(lat) +","+ str(long))
  return geo
```

I have this error in using the above example:

```
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\mapjobs\main.py", line 18, in get_geo
    data = json.loads(result.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 310, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 346, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 0):

It should include the `browser_key`, and the url should be:

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key="+ browser_key +"&address=" + address + "&sensor="+ sensor
```